# API call to Delete from facebook news feed (facebook.stackowerflow)

Tags: facebook, feed

I'm sorry for the cross posting, but it seems that I posted question to the general stackoverflow (not to facebook one).
([API call to Delete from facebook news feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887114/api-call-to-delete-from-facebook-news-feed))

Could you please help?
When the user (let it be Arnold) posts some link to his friend's wall (to Chuck) via my app, the FB also makes a post in a Chuck's news feed (with the same link). The question is - is there any FB API ability to delete the message from the Chuck's news feed?

Once the Chuck clicks the link posted by Arnold on Chucks wall, the same link on the news feed becomes no longer valid. So I need to drop the news feed post (but not the wall post) as link is disposable, but in the news feed looks like "new".

In the FB documents (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) under home section (This connection corresponds to the News Feed) I have not found any mentions about the ability to delete posts from news feed.

However there is an ability to delete a post. And somewhere on forums mentioned an ability to set is_hide=true to the news feed posts.

Dear guys, could you please suggest is there an ability to hide/delete news feed posts? Where I can find documentation about that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [API call to Delete from facebook news feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887114/api-call-to-delete-from-facebook-news-feed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete any Facebook Graph object if you have the appropriate permissions using the http delete method (or you can append method=delete to your api call.

e.g:http://www.facebook.com/[user_id]/posts/[post_id]?method=delete&access_token=[access_token]

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for the answer. But how I can get the news feed post id? As the news feed being created by FB automatically for the wall post? When I make a wall post, I know then ID of the post, but not the news feed id?

Comment: So far as I am aware, it's the same, if you delete the post you'll also delete the news feed post. I don't think you can delete the news feed post without also deleting the post.

Comment: So, it seems that there is no ability to delete/hide news feed record without deletion of wall post, right?